# Fantasy book about a child crossing a door and arriving to the world of "forgotten things"

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this fantasy book as a child from a library, and I have tried to find its name since then.

It's about a child that can not remember his father, and after some research he finds that his father crossed a gate. I am pretty sure that is the Gate Of Ishtar but I don't remember.

Then he arrives to a world where the Forgotten Things of our world go when they are forgotten.

The most characteristic details I can remember are:

1. The kid became friends with a Glass Bird that in our world was from India.
2. There was a desert with moving rocks that have the name of the people of the world, and if you find yours you could remember everything.

Some more "blurry" details that I can not assure totally because my memory may fail:
The main enemy was Nebuchadnezzar, or another Sumerian/Babylonian king.
The father of the kid was an archeologist.
The cover is The Ishtar Gate.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  About what year would you have read this?  Do you remember the cover/art at all?

Comment: @DavidW Thanks for welcoming :) I think around year 1998-2000 and I think that maybe the cover was the Door of Ishtar, or something similar but could be just my imagination

Comment: [*The Book of Lost Things*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Book_of_Lost_Things) feels adjacent, but not quite right.

Comment: @user146074  Is English your first language?  In English a door is a moveable object that can close a doorway or be  opened to let people enter.   And I have never heard of anything called "the door of Ishtar" but I have read of "The Ishtar Gate".  I think that you meant to write that the boy "passes through a gateway" instead of "crsssing a door".

Comment: @M.A.Golding English is not my first language, thanks a lot for pointing about door/gate, I was indeed referring to Ishtar Gate. I have edited so now is clearer

Answer (score 2):

Das Museum der Gestohlenen Erinnerungen ("The Museum of Stolen Memories") by Ralf Isau. From the [author's website](http://www.isau.de/pdfs/museum_e.pdf):

> Stone figures suddenly come to life and prowl round the dark museum. Memories disappear from the heads of people. Strange things are going on in Berlin.
>
> When the twins Oliver and Jessica return home from their holidays, they have forgotten all about their father. All that remains is an unsettling feeling of emptiness. There is absolutely no trace of their father. The police appear on the scene - they, too, are looking for Thomas Pollock, claiming that the twins' father has stolen an ancient golden statue from the Pergamon Museum.
>
> Later, in the dusty mess up in the attic, Oliver and Jessica find a trunk with the last remaining mementos of their dead mother, such as a large jar full of hair slides. They also find a diary belonging to their father. They are amazed to read in his records that the present night watchman was once a respected scientist at the Pergamon Museum. He then goes on to write about Quassinja, the realm of lost memories, and Xexano, the ancient Babylonian god of this mysterious world. Father has discovered that a second, much older gate is hidden under the reconstructed world-famous Ishtar Gate in the Pergamon Museum.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  I can't find much information about that book, but it appears to feature twins, not a single child.   You should add details about the book to your answer to explain how it matches the question.

Comment: A unique point mentioned by the OP is the glass bird.  Does anything like that appear in this book?